# How to position dropdown or drop up according to table size

Tags: css, angularjs, dropdown

I have dropdown inside a table I need to change it to dropup if there is no space in table below that row. How can I achieve it? can some one help 
sample code http://jsfiddle.net/mhu23/YZx7R/22/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="row in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]">
                    <td> <a>{{row}}</a>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <!-- To create dropups instead of dropdowns i could add the class "dropup" to the li-element below. -->
                            <!-- But what I need is an inteligent mechanism that decides when to use dropdown and when to use dropup -->
                            <li class="dropdown pull-right"> <a class="btn-link dropdown-toggle">
                                <i class="icon-align-justify"></i>
                            </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li ng-repeat="menu in [1,2,3]"> <a class="btn-link">{{menu}}</a>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `$last` attribute

Something like:

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right"
     ng-class="{'dropup':$last}">
```

<kbd>[Fixed Fillde](http://jsfiddle.net/gmva8y20/)</kbd>

---

If you need last 2, you can write:

```
ng-class="{'dropup': $index >= items.length-2}"
```

where `items=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]`

<kbd>[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/g2cL976w/)</kbd>

Comment: Soustin some times second last one also needed to change to dropup. Need to calculate space and then decide

Comment: @Iceberg added a new option. I think you can continue from this point